# Laravel 5.5 not reading session auth cookie

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have 2 domains in the system:
`client.example.com`
`server.example.com`

The client has some html forms for the login and registration.
Any way, this is how I am login:

```
Auth::login($login); // the login is success
dd(Auth::user()); // will print the user
```

The cookie is set in the browser for domain`.example.com` as configured.
Few seconds after Im making another request to `server.example.com` I see the cookie is sent back in the request `"Cookie":"laravel_session=...."` but, the problem is that user is null `Auth::user()`.

From my point of view, everithing is ok.
Im using `withCredencials` ajax, my cors supports credencials, im using domain ".example.com"

what can be wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is authorized for `client.example.com` not `server.example.com`. You need to set the domain as `*.example.com` for it to cross the subdomain boundary.